# Consistent Location of HTML Pages in Spring Boot

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, resources

I'm having a silly issue that I can't find how to fix. When I run my SpringBoot app using:

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

It does find the HTML pages at `src/main/webapp`. However, when I package the app and run it in the other server it doesn't:

```
mvn clean package
copy myapp.jar --> to other server
[switch to the other server]
java -jar myapp.jar
```

It doesn't find the pages at `src/main/webapp` anymore. It still finds -- however -- find pages at `src/main/resources/static`.

I would prefer a single consistent behavior, either both ways allowing "webapp" or both not allowing it.

How can make both executions work the same way?